# Cordova access origin=".*" vs origin="*"

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

What is the difference between `<access origin=".*">` vs `< access origin="*">`. Cordova docs state that simply `origin="*"` should allow all access to external websites. However while trying to get `fileTransfer.download()` to work, a lot of people suggest using `origin = ".*"`. What is the difference?

Link To Cordova Definition of "*": http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Link To Answer Saying Use ".*":
[android phonegap FileTransfer.download() recieving error code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765085/android-phonegap-filetransfer-download-recieving-error-code-3)

Comment: can you show some link where `origin = ".*"` this is suggested? I want to see why this is suggested and this will more clarify your question.

Comment: @AtanuCSE please see edits above.